# Add Window Close Button To Menu Bar -- C++

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to write an application that does not have a title/caption bar (a gross waste of screen real estate).  So, I wish to add a close button ("X") to the end of the menu bar.  Here is the code that I have tried:

```
mII.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
mII.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_BITMAP;
mII.fType = MFT_BITMAP | MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY;
mII.hbmpItem = HBMMENU_MBAR_CLOSE;
InsertMenuItem(hMenu, NUMMI, TRUE, &mII);
DrawMenuBar(hwnd);
```

In this case, "NUMMI" is equal to 5, the current number of main-menu items (numbered '0' through '4').  The new close button would be item number '5'.

However, the code seems to do *nothing!*  No button appears on the menu bar.  Am I missing something?

Comment: `MIIM_BITMAP` and `MFT_BITMAP` don't go together. Use one of the other, not both. If you want to use `hbmpItem` then use `MIIM_BITMAP`. If you use `MFT_BITMAP` then you need to put the `HBITMAP` in `dwTypeData` instead. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Remy.  I eliminated the `MFT_BITMAP` flag, and now, it works.  The MS documentation did not make this clear.

For those who might be reading this, asking the same question, I should note, that the above code only *displays* the button.  Functionality must be added, just like any other button or menu item.  A unique identifier is assigned to the `wID` member of the structure.  The command is handled in the `WM_COMMAND` case, along with the other menu items.

Here is the revised, working code:

```
mII.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
mII.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_BITMAP;
mII.fType = MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY;
mII.wID = ID_MENUBAR_CLOSE;
mII.hbmpItem = HBMMENU_MBAR_CLOSE;
InsertMenuItem(hMenu, NUMMI, TRUE, &mII);
DrawMenuBar(hwnd);
```

`ID_MENUBAR_CLOSE` is a macro, defining a unique number that I assigned to this button.  The command is the handled in the `WM_COMMAND` case:

```
case ID_MENUBAR_CLOSE:
     SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0L);  return 0;
     return 0;
```

*Voila*, a working close button on the menu bar.